# launch spinner on click of a button

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm working on `Xamarin android`. I want a spinner to show up on a button click or the spinner should be on top of a button, the other way I can say. Sounds crazy but that's the stuff I got in my head a couple of days back! Yeah I've seen [Spinner](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/controls/spinner/). May be what I'm asking is not part of the plan, but I wanna implement that!

> UPDATE 2: Let me explain with an example.
>
> Consider the [Web 2.0 scientific calculator](https://web2.0calc.com/). There is a `button π`. You long press the button and you will get a drop down. The constant that you select from the drop down will be displayed in the `textbox`.  I want the same functionality with the spinner. Just the difference is I want it on the button click rather than a long press. Hope I'm clear now.

That's the part of code I tried with:

```
<!--main.axml-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/myTitle">

            <!--some stuff-->

            <ImageButton android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/btnPi"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:padding="100dip"
            android:src="@drawable/pi" /> 
      <Spinner
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:id="@+id/btnConst"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:prompt="@string/cons" />

     <!--And few other stuffs-->
</LinearLayout>

<!--Strings.xml-->

<string name="cons">const</string>
  <string-array name="ConsArray">
    <item>Angstrom star</item>
    <item>Faraday constant</item>
    <item>Planck constant</item>
    <item>Rydberg constant</item>
    <item>Stefan-Boltzmann constant</item>
    <item>electric constant</item>
    <item>mag. constant</item>
    <item>neutron mass</item>
  </string-array>
```

It doesn't matter's to me whether I use a `Button` or a `ImageButton` ! I'm happy with either of it. Basically I just want a drop-down menu to popup, as soon as I click that button. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: When I worked on [York Shen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46578791/5588347) , I got this blank space occupied by the spinner: [image: like this]

Answer (score 1):

> I want a spinner to show up on a button click.

You could put a `Button` on `Spinner` by using a `FrameLayout` :

```
 <FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/planet_prompt"

    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_spinner"
        android:text="Spinner Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
 </FrameLayout>
```

Then, every time your `Button` is click, you could use `spinner.PerformClick()` method to show your `Spinner` :

```
bt_spinner.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    spinner.PerformClick();
};
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SulWp.gif).

**Update :**

I cant reproduce your problem, but here is my complete code from the [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/controls/spinner/), you could use it and try again :

```
spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spinner_ItemSelected);
var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.planets_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);  

adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
spinner.Adapter = adapter;
bt_spinner.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    spinner.PerformClick();
};

...

private void spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;

    string toast = string.Format("The planet is {0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position));
    Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

Comment: yup but the spinner occupies the space! I will put the image in the post.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava, I have update my answer, please check it, and if this cant solve your problem, we need to see some code and to help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Hi Shen!  I have updated my question with an example. Hopefully that I made sense this time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava, I have read your explanation, but I cant reproduce your problem " blank space occupied by the spinner", I cant find the reason, so could you please share some code?

Comment: @AshishSrivastava, what is your `Activity` **style**.

Comment: Did you mean about the theme? Mine is Light.Panel

Comment: Try using `FrameLayout` and delete the line : `android:visibility="invisible"` in your `Spinner`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156092/discussion-between-ashish-srivastava-and-york-shen-msft).

Answer (score 0):

In your XAML, set the spinner to not be visible. In your onClick event, set change the visibility. You may have to do more in onClick if you want the things below the spinner in the linear layout to move out of the way.